# I have a trouble with lowagie pdf and Report Making. I cant include headerfooter on the first page

Tags: java, spring, pdf, paragraph

[This is an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBABS.jpg) I am working with the lowagie PDF library in a Java Spring development. I need to make a report on a landscape orientation. I have also added a headerfooter. The report has 5 pages. I have included a table. Everything seems to work fine on pages 2,3,4 and 5. But in page 1 I can not make it happen. The headerfooter and the paragraphs I added dont appear. Im terribly tired. I do not know what else to do. Does someone faced the same situation before? i would really appreciate some help.

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
package com.gambbate.faqu.viewresolver;

import com.gambbate.faqu.model.Usuario;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;

import com.lowagie.text.Chunk;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.Element;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.FontFactory;
import com.lowagie.text.HeaderFooter;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.Phrase;
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.awt.Color;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractPdfView;

/**
 *
 * @author Pisner-Lichtenstein
 */
public class PdfView extends AbstractPdfView {

    @Override
    protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> map,
            Document dcmnt,
            PdfWriter writer,
            HttpServletRequest hsr,
            HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception {

        List<Usuario> listadoDeUsuarios = (List<Usuario>) map.get("listadoDeUsuarios");

        PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(8);
        tabla.setWidthPercentage(100);

        tabla.setWidths(new float[]{2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 2.0f, 1.5f, 2.0f, 2.0f});

        PdfPCell encabezadoCelda = new PdfPCell();
        encabezadoCelda.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        encabezadoCelda.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        encabezadoCelda.setPadding(5);

        encabezadoCelda.setBorderColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        encabezadoCelda.setBorderWidth(0.15f);

        Font fuente = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD);
        fuente.setSize(10);
        fuente.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        encabezadoCelda.setFixedHeight(30);
        encabezadoCelda.setPadding(5);
        encabezadoCelda.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);

        encabezadoCelda.setPhrase(new Phrase("Nombre", fuente));
        tabla.addCell(encabezadoCelda);

        encabezadoCelda.setPhrase(new Phrase("Apellido", fuente));
        tabla.addCell(encabezadoCelda);

        encabezadoCelda.setPhrase(new Phrase("Fecha de Nac.", fuente));
        tabla.addCell(encabezadoCelda);

        encabezadoCelda.setPhrase(new Phrase("Email", fuente));
        tabla.addCell(encabezadoCelda);

        encabezadoCelda.setPhrase(new Phrase("Celular", fuente));
        tabla.addCell(encabezadoCelda);

        encabezadoCelda.setPhrase(new Phrase("Interno", fuente));
        tabla.addCell(encabezadoCelda);

        encabezadoCelda.setPhrase(new Phrase("Gerencia", fuente));
        tabla.addCell(encabezadoCelda);

        encabezadoCelda.setPhrase(new Phrase("Puesto", fuente));
        tabla.addCell(encabezadoCelda);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        int colorDeFondo = 0;

        for (Usuario listadoDeUsuario : listadoDeUsuarios) {

            PdfPCell cd = new PdfPCell();

            cd.setBorderColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            cd.setBorderWidth(0.15f);

            fuente = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA);
            fuente.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            fuente.setSize(10);
            cd.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            cd.setPadding(5);
            cd.setFixedHeight(30);

            if (colorDeFondo % 2 == 0) {
                cd.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                cd.setBackgroundColor(new Color(245, 245, 245));
            }

            colorDeFondo++;

            cd.setPhrase(new Phrase(listadoDeUsuario.getNombre(), fuente));
            tabla.addCell(cd);

            cd.setPhrase(new Phrase(listadoDeUsuario.getApellido(), fuente));
            tabla.addCell(cd);

            cd.setPhrase(new Phrase(sdf.format(listadoDeUsuario.getFechaDeNacimiento()), fuente));
            cd.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            tabla.addCell(cd);

            cd.setPhrase(new Phrase(listadoDeUsuario.getEmailCorporativo(), fuente));
            cd.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            tabla.addCell(cd);

            cd.setPhrase(new Phrase(listadoDeUsuario.getCelular(), fuente));
            cd.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            tabla.addCell(cd);

            cd.setPhrase(new Phrase(listadoDeUsuario.getInterno(), fuente));
            cd.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            tabla.addCell(cd);

            cd.setPhrase(new Phrase(listadoDeUsuario.getGerencia().getGerencia(), fuente));
            cd.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            tabla.addCell(cd);

            cd.setPhrase(new Phrase(listadoDeUsuario.getPuesto().getPuesto(), fuente));
            cd.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            tabla.addCell(cd);

        }

        tabla.setSpacingBefore(25);
        tabla.setHeaderRows(1);

        Paragraph encabezado = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Gambbate - Faqu Soft", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 15)));
        Paragraph reporteTitulo = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Recursos Humanos - Listado de Uuarios", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 15)));
        Paragraph autor = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Emitido por:" + map.get("nombreDeUsuario"), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 15)));
        Paragraph fecha = new Paragraph(new Chunk("Fecha de Emision:" + new Date(), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 15)));

        HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("fewfwfewwwe"), false);
        HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("aaaaaaaaaaaa"), false);

        dcmnt.setHeader(header);
        dcmnt.setFooter(footer);

        dcmnt.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        dcmnt.setMargins(60, 30, 30, 30);

        dcmnt.add(encabezado);
        dcmnt.add(reporteTitulo);
        dcmnt.add(tabla);

    }

}
```

Comment: you don't show any code. Thus, what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: you are right, im sorry. i forgot to write the code. Here you are. I would really appreciiate some help:

Comment: you should try setting header and footer (and page doze and margin) information *before* you open the document. You appear to have already called `open` before using `buildPdfDocument`, though.

Comment: but i never called open.is a builder that is launched when the link is called.

Comment: besides i can not put the orientation configuration either in the first page. im so disapointed...

Comment: @mkl do you know why is this happening?

Comment: Not calling `dcmnt.open ()` at all is wrong. I thought the caller of your method did. But if you want any page related settings to already work oon the first page, you have to do such settings before opening the document which in turn you habe to do before adding any content to the document.

Comment: @mkl unfortunately it did not work. I am so worried. can someone help me?

Comment: *"unfortunately it did not work"* - then you are doing it incorrectly. For more detailed help please share the code that actually creates and initializes the `Document` instance.

Comment: the code is shared in the beggining of the post.

Comment: I just said i tried to add the dcmnt.open() sentence in the end and rearrange the commands as you told me. But it did not work. I can not make it happen

Comment: *"the code is shared in the beggining of the post."* - The code that actually creates and initializes the `Document` instance is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments to the question, if a page setting already is required at the creation time of a page (like its dimension and orientation), and if you want to change it already for the first page, you need to set the property *before* opening the `Document` because the first page is created during that opening routine.

In the case at hand the `PageSize` and the `Margins` are of interest. To change them already for the first page, you can do it like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("landscape.pdf"));
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
document.setMargins(60, 30, 30, 30);
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph("Test string for a landscape PDF."));
document.close();
```

The result is:

[image: Screenshot]

As you see

- the first page already is in landscape and
- the first page uses the predefined margins, in particular the left margin is twice as large as the top margin which it is not by default.

Thus, all you have to do is search the calling code of your `buildPdfDocument` method, find the `Document` and `PdfWriter` instantiation in there (similar to

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("landscape.pdf"));
```

), and set the `PageSize` and the `Margins` (like

```
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
document.setMargins(60, 30, 30, 30);
```

) before the `Document` method `open` is called (like

```
document.open();
```

).

---

In your case that code is in the method `renderMergedOutputModel` of the `AbstractPdfView` class from which your class is derived:

```
[...]
Document document = getDocument();
PdfWriter writer = newWriter(document, baos);

// Apply preferences and build metadata.
prepareWriter(model, writer, request);
buildPdfMetadata(model, document, request);

// Build PDF document.
document.open();
[...]
```

But you do not have to patch this base class; as you see certain methods are called right before `document.open()`, in particular `buildPdfMetadata` which is documented as:

```
/**
 * Populate the iText Document's meta fields (author, title, etc.).
 * <br>Default is an empty implementation. Subclasses may override this method
 * to add meta fields such as title, subject, author, creator, keywords, etc.
 * This method is called after assigning a PdfWriter to the Document and
 * before calling <code>document.open()</code>.
 * @param model the model, in case meta information must be populated from it
 * @param document the iText document being populated
 * @param request in case we need locale etc. Shouldn't look at attributes.
 * @see com.lowagie.text.Document#addTitle
 * @see com.lowagie.text.Document#addSubject
 * @see com.lowagie.text.Document#addKeywords
 * @see com.lowagie.text.Document#addAuthor
 * @see com.lowagie.text.Document#addCreator
 * @see com.lowagie.text.Document#addProducer
 * @see com.lowagie.text.Document#addCreationDate
 * @see com.lowagie.text.Document#addHeader
*/
protected void buildPdfMetadata(Map model, Document document, HttpServletRequest request)
```

This method is better for your use case than `prepareWriter` because it has the `Document document` as parameter.

Thus, all you have to do is override that method in your class:

```
protected void buildPdfMetadata(Map model, Document document, HttpServletRequest request) {
    super.buildPdfMetadata(model, document, request);
    document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    document.setMargins(60, 30, 30, 30);
}
```